# How to use jq to create a clean json template file without values

Tags: json, templates, jq

I'm trying to create a "template" of a .json configuration file, in which all the keys are present (and the structure is completely preserved), but all the values (which may contain sensitive data such as database credentials) are removed. This "cleaned" file may then be committed to source control as a template file.

Input **file.json**:

```json
{
    "global_foo": "987",
    "global_bar": "qwertz",
    "global_baz": "123",
    "environment_a": [
        {
            "name": "baz",
            "value": "456"
        }
    ],
    "environment_b": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": "123"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "value": "abc"
        }
    ],
    "environment_test": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired output** (i.e., replace all top-level values with empty strings, and replace leaf values with key 'value', see nested values in `environment_*`, with empty strings).

```json
{
    "global_foo": "",
    "global_bar": "",
    "global_baz": "",
    "environment_a": [
        {
            "name": "baz",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "environment_b": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "environment_test": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

An obvious solution is `jq`, but I'm not very familiar with it yet. What I tried so far (this does **not** work with multiple `environment_*` arrays, but only works with a single one called "environment"): https://jqplay.org/s/cK2Bn5OR54

I'm looking for a solution which covers an arbitrary number of `environment_*` (top-level keys beginning with `environment_` and not only a single one). Additionally, I'm sure that my attempt is overly complicated and there exists a more elegant solution.

Many thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update every string value with the empty string except those with the keyname **name**.

```
reduce (paths(strings) | select(.[-1] != "name")) as $p (.; setpath($p; ""))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NpsHyg2uUq)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could start with this:

```
walk(if type == "object"
     then with_entries(
       if .key != "name" and (.value|type)=="string"
       then .value="" else . end)
     else . end)
```

https://jqplay.org/s/1tNFqGiYsO